# Implementing the sign function with basic math

Tags: functions

The [$\operatorname{sign}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) function returns:
$$
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
\phantom{-}0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\phantom{-}1 & \text{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

How do I implement this with only basic math principles (addition, subtract, multiplication, division, powers, square roots)?

Comment: Choice from alternatives is also a basic math principle.  You have a fine definition of the function.

Comment: @RossMillikan indeed, the idea is simpler than that, the $\text{sgn}$ function basically being a monadic encapsulation of the order on the real line.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\text{sgn}(x)$ is not a continuous function on $\mathbb R$, but all the elementary operations are continuous on $\mathbb R$(except the division, it may be undefined at some certain points) and the composite of continuous functions are also continuous, you **cannot** find a way to represent $\text{sgn}(x)$ in elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean to call the "basic math principles" (where I'd include trigonometric functions and logarithms too) are ultimately the result of compositions of functions which are continuous on their domains. Therefore any resulting function must be continuous on its domain as well, which isn't the case for $\operatorname{sgn}$.

**If** you are one of the people who believe that the map $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ should be defined on $((0,\infty)\times \Bbb R)\cup (\{0\}\times [0,\infty))$ by imposing $0^0=1$ (I don't exactly count myself in that number), then the considerations above no longer apply, and with the help of $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$ you can write $$\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\frac{x}{0^{\sqrt{x^2}}+\sqrt{x^2}}$$

Comment: It is such a shame that the expression $0^0$ does not return a unique value (or even a finite number of different values); otherwise it would have been the natural choice here...