# The signum function expressed using a single formula

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers

The signum function is defined as a piecewise function:  $\operatorname{sgn} (x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   1,x>0  \\
   0,x=0  \\
   -1,x<0  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$.

Naturally, we could simplify this: $\operatorname{sgn}  (x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\left| x \right|}{x},x\ne 0  \\
   0,x=0  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$.

I’m just wondering is it possible to define this function using a single formula? I understand that the absolute value $\left| x \right|$ is a piecewise function itself but for the sake of this question let’s assume we are allowed to use modulus to define the signum function.

Edit:

I completely agree with the answers given below; however, my original question was about the possibility to define the signum function using only elementary functions and the absolute value function (which itself is not an elementary function) in such a way that would require exactly one formula (i.e., avoiding a piecewise function).
For example, the following function $g\left( x \right)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   x,x>0  \\
   0,x\le 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$ can be defined in such a manner: $g\left( x \right)=\frac{x+\left| x \right|}{2}$.

Comment: Some ideas here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962979/implementing-the-sign-function-with-basic-math

Comment: I guess the answer really depends on what you consider acceptable. Technically speaking, a piecewise definition _is_ a single formula. You may describe it as a Fourier series if you want, but then again, it depends on what are the symbols you allow in your formula.

Comment: I guess people just don't like writing indicator functions like $1_{(0,\infty)}(x)-1_{(-\infty,0)}(x)$ ... Fortunately when the time comes to apply Fubini-Tonelli their latent love for crying comes to fruition.

Comment: He who accepts $|x|$ as a "primitive" function should also accept $\text{sgn}(x)$ as such.

Comment: @user65203 Indeed one could argue that $\text{sgn}(x)$ is more primitive than $|x|$ since we can write $x\,\text{sgn}(x)=|x|.$

Answer (score 1):

Using only the arithmetic operations, the identity function and the absolute value, this does not seem possible, because the $\text{sgn}$ function is discontinuous. As far as I see, a discontinuity can only appear with a division by zero, which results in an undefined value in at least one point.